# How to make a subdomain permanent redirect?

Tags: domain-name-system, subdomain, redirection

I have a new vps CentOS 5.3 with Webmin, BIND, Apache installed. I want install Shoucast 2 server on port 8000. Can i create subdomain (ex: **radio.mystation.com**) and redirect it to **mystation.com:8000/radio** (with Shoucast 2 stream path/id) ? How?

In others shared server, i can do that with my cPanel (Subdomain Manage Redirection).

> **test.yohang.net** is currently being redirected to: http://yohang.net:8000/radio

When i open **test.yohang.net** (ex: Winamp), the player can stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SHOUTcast is close enough to HTTP to allow for 301 and 302 redirects.  You need something on a web server at http://radio.mystation.com that can send the appropriate redirect header.

Here is how you could easily do it with PHP:

```
header('Location: http://mystation.com:8000/radio');
```

PHP will automatically add the 302 status code for you.  You can use 301 instead to make this "permanent", but be careful, as it is possible for this to cached, and you won't ever be able to change it.

To do a permanent redirect, put this above the prior line:

```
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
```